# ContactForm7 and sweetallert2 does not work after update

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, sweetalert2

recently updated ContactForm7 and found that [sweetallert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) does not work any more

script is connected as follows

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'swal_contact', 999 );
function swal_contact() {
    $title_success = get_option('swal_cf7_title_success');
    $duration_success = get_option('swal_cf7_duration_success');
    $title_error = get_option('swal_cf7_title_error');
    $duration_error = get_option('swal_cf7_duration_error');
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('form.wpcf7-form input, form.wpcf7-form textarea').on("input", function(e) {
                $(this).removeClass("input-error");
            })
            $(".wpcf7-submit").click(function(event) {
                var form = $(this).closest("form");
                $(".input-error").removeClass("input-error");
                $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                    var validMessage = function(){
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Done!',
                            html: 'Thank you for your message.<br>We will contact you shortly.',
                            showCancelButton: false,
                        });
                    };
                    var errorMessage = function(){
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'warning',
                            title: 'Error',
                            html: 'One or more fields have an error.<br>Please check and try again.',
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            showClass: {
                                popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'
                            }
                        });
                    };
                    setSwal = $("form.wpcf7-form").hasClass("invalid") ? "alert" : "success";
                    if ( setSwal === "alert" ) { 
                        errorMessage();
                        $(form).find("[aria-invalid='true']").addClass("input-error");
                    };
                    if ( setSwal === "success" ) { validMessage() };
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

[here page where help is needed](https://u1455669.isp.regruhosting.ru/)

what am i doing wrong?

last version where everything worked was 5.3

Comment: `ajaxComplete` is deprecated.  So is `click`

Comment: can't understand what's wrong now events are still not handled correctly tell me what function else deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

There's been some changes to contact form 7.  You need to listen for this `wpcf7mailsent` - This is what worked for me.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form.wpcf7-form input, form.wpcf7-form textarea').on("input", function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass("input-error");
    })
    $(".wpcf7-submit").on( 'click', function(event) {
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            let message = $('.wpcf7-response-output').text();
            let validMessage = function(){
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Done!',
                    html: 'Thank you for your message.<br>We will contact you shortly.',
                    showCancelButton: false,
                });
            };
            var errorMessage = function(){
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'warning',
                    title: 'Error',
                    html: 'One or more fields have an error.<br>Please check and try again.',
                    showCancelButton: false,
                    showClass: {
                        popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'
                    }
                });
            };
            setSwal = $("form.wpcf7-form").hasClass("invalid") ? "alert" : "success";
            if ( setSwal === "alert" ) {
                errorMessage();
                $(form).find("[aria-invalid='true']").addClass("input-error");
            };
            if ( setSwal === "success" ) { validMessage() };
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your are best. Thank your

Comment: @Epifan The way this site works, is you accept answers and upvote them if they are helpful.